# Does this transformation need a group by?

Tags: oracle, xslt, group-by

I have a XSL transformation (XSLT 1.0) that gets the following data in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<PsWeIni025StgCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/top/DB_SEL_MSR_PPLSFT">
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144232</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>1</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0085400</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144232</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>2</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0074255</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144232</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>3</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0174400</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144232</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>4</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0171400</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144232</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>5</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0144000</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144233</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>1</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0085400</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144233</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>2</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0074255</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
  <PsWeIni025Stg>
    <origOprid>TL47695</origOprid>
    <orderNo>MSR0144233</orderNo>
    <orderIntLineNo>3</orderIntLineNo>
    <invItemId>0144000</invItemId>
    <businessUnit>10TOC</businessUnit>
    <distribType></distribType>
    <operatingUnit>10000</operatingUnit>
    <actionFlg>A</actionFlg>
  </PsWeIni025Stg>
</PsWeIni025StgCollection>
```

Essentially we need to break the PsWeIni025Stg elements down and group the orderNo together. So the first orderNo MSR0144232 has 5 entries and the second orderNo MSR0144233 has 3 entries. This is a slimmed down version.

```
INVUSE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
INVUSE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
   INVUSELINE
   INVRESERVE
```

This is a more detailed version of what we need to the output to look like is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncZXQINVRESERVE xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.Company.com/Common/Logging/V1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/EAM_MaterialStockRequests/PPLSFT_MaterialStockRequest_ABCS_req/DB_SEL_MSR_PPLSFT" xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.Company.com/Common/Errors/V1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.Company.com/core/CommonTypes/V1.0" xmlns:mxws="http://www.ibm.com/maximo/wsdl/ZXQWSPS_ZXQMXINVRESInterface" xmlns:tns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:pc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
  <tns:ZXQINVRESERVESet>
    <tns:INVUSE>
      <tns:AUTOCREATED>TL47695</tns:AUTOCREATED>
      <tns:DESCRIPTION>MSR:MSR0144234 3101100028</tns:DESCRIPTION>
      <tns:ZXQMSRNUM>MSR0144234</tns:ZXQMSRNUM>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>1</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0085400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144234</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0085400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>2</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0074255</tns:ITEMNUM>       
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144234</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0074255</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>3</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0174400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144234</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0174400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
    </tns:INVUSE>
    <tns:INVUSE>
      <tns:AUTOCREATED>TL47695</tns:AUTOCREATED>
      <tns:DESCRIPTION>MSR:MSR0144235 3101100028</tns:DESCRIPTION>
      <tns:ZXQMSRNUM>MSR0144235</tns:ZXQMSRNUM>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>1</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0085400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144235</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0085400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>2</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0162801</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144235</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0162801</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>3</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0171400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144235</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0171400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
    </tns:INVUSE>
    <tns:INVUSE>
      <tns:AUTOCREATED>TL47695</tns:AUTOCREATED>
      <tns:DESCRIPTION>MSR:MSR0144236 3101100028</tns:DESCRIPTION>
      <tns:ZXQMSRNUM>MSR0144236</tns:ZXQMSRNUM>
        <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>1</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0085400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144236</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0085400</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>2</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0110900</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144236</tns:EXTERNALREFID> 
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0110900</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
      <tns:INVUSELINE>
        <tns:FROMSTORELOC>10TOC</tns:FROMSTORELOC>
        <tns:INVUSELINENUM>3</tns:INVUSELINENUM>
        <tns:ITEMNUM>0114300</tns:ITEMNUM>
        <tns:INVRESERVE action="Add">
          <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
          <tns:EXTERNALREFID>MSR0144236</tns:EXTERNALREFID>
          <tns:ITEMNUM>0114300</tns:ITEMNUM>
        </tns:INVRESERVE>
      </tns:INVUSELINE>
    </tns:INVUSE>
```

Would this be a good case for a group by? Or is there another operation I should use to achieve the desired result. I was looking at the for-each-group too, perhaps I could use that. I could group on the orderNo. I am guessing if so I should convert this to XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Please explain the logic of the required transformation. Minimizing the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem would also be welcome.

Comment: Just taking one element in your output at random, the string "10000-10000-1840001-E100-03101-03101-07M200-3101100028" appears twice in the output and doesn't appear at all in the input. So how on earth are we expected to understand what this transformation is doing?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I minimized the example and added some explanation to the logic.

Comment: @MichaelKay I removed some of the less important elements that cluttered it up.

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is accomplished using the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). I suggest you read the article, browse some of  the numerous example of the method here on SO, and come back if you run into a **specific** problem implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue  with the for each group. This is an slimmed down version of the solution that I finally got working.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:SyncZXQINVRESERVE>
      <tns:ZXQINVRESERVESet>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:PsWeIni025StgCollection/ns0:PsWeIni025Stg" group-by="ns0:orderNo">
          <tns:INVUSE>
            <tns:AUTOCREATED>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:origOprid"/>
            </tns:AUTOCREATED>
            <tns:CHANGEBY>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:origOprid"/>
            </tns:CHANGEBY>
            <tns:CHANGEDATE>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:demandDate"/>
            </tns:CHANGEDATE>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:sort select="ns0:orderIntLineNo"/>
              <xsl:variable name="action">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="ns0:cancelDttm != ''">Delete</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="string-length(ns0:actionFlg)> 0 and ns0:actionFlg = 'A'">Add</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>AddChange</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:variable>
              <tns:INVUSELINE>
                <tns:ACTUALDATE>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:demandDate"/>
                </tns:ACTUALDATE>
                <tns:INVUSELINENUM>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:orderIntLineNo"/>
                </tns:INVUSELINENUM>
                <tns:ITEMNUM>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:invItemId"/>
                </tns:ITEMNUM>
                <tns:ITEMSETID>SHARE</tns:ITEMSETID>
                <tns:LINETYPE>ITEM</tns:LINETYPE>
                <tns:LOCATION>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:businessUnit"/>
                </tns:LOCATION>
                <tns:QUANTITY>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:qtyRequested"/>
                </tns:QUANTITY>
                <tns:USETYPE>ISSUE</tns:USETYPE>
                <tns:INVRESERVE action="{$action}">
                  <tns:ACTUALQTY>0</tns:ACTUALQTY>
                  <tns:EXTERNALREFID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:orderNo"/>
                  </tns:EXTERNALREFID>
                </tns:INVRESERVE>
              </tns:INVUSELINE>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tns:INVUSE>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </tns:ZXQINVRESERVESet>
    </tns:SyncZXQINVRESERVE>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is an XSLT 2.0 solution. Nothing wrong with that, but your question was about XSLT 1.0.